# sscanf() in a while loop in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have a string `input` which contains words separated by white-space. I want to use `sscanf()` to split the words, store each word in `input_word` and print it, but I'm not sure how to put it in a while loop.

This is what I have:

```
 char input[max];
 char split_input[max];

 /* input gets populated here */

 while (sscanf(input," %s", split_input)) {
     printf("[%s]\n", split_input);
 }
```

What would be the condition to terminate the loop as soon as the last word in the sequence is split?

Comment: See [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, the `scanf` family returns `EOF` on end of input. As far as I know, that has always been defined as -1, though there could be platforms that defined it differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're using the wrong function there. Might I suggest `strtok()` instead?

Read here for [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Answer (score 4):

Might not cover all corner cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char *input = "abc def ghi ";
    char split_input[sizeof input];
    int n;

    while (sscanf(input," %s%n", split_input, &n) == 1) {
        printf("[%s]\n", split_input);
        input += n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest the **[strtok()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)** function. It tokenizes your string and allows you to extract the words one by one within a loop. This is an example, assuming `input` is your defined string, I write a function that does that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int tokenize(char *input) {

    const char space[2] = " ";
    char *token = strtok(input, space);
    while (token != NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL, space);
        printf("%s\n", token);
    }

    return 0;
}
```